# Does the ending of episode 2 makes a drastic change?

Tags: life-is-strange

In the ending of episode 2 you can

> prevent Kate from commiting suicide. However, does this action change the whole story drastically or is it only the ending of this episode that is affected by failing to do so? Does she stay at the academy after the events of episode 2 an can be anyhow interacted with? Or in other words - is it beneficial somehow to the whole plot to save her (like she gives any clues as to what's happening or what was the thing about her and David-the-security-officer)?

While I know this question is not spoiler-free, and the answers won't be too, please limit your answer to yes/no with minimal explanation of how this affects future episodes. As I have failed to do it the right way, I might want to re-do this episode, but if it's for only 2 second video change (episode 2 epilogue) I might also get over with it anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If Kate survives, she does appear later but she doesn't drastically affect the plot. After the suicide attempt, Kate is in hospital so isn't at Blackwell. However, she will text you and later you will get to visit her in the hospital.

Comment: She will also help you spot Prescott's room, not that it is too hard or important though.